# Can't read integral method

Tags: integration, matlab

I type this :

```
fun = @(x) exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2; 
q = integral(fun,2,4); 
q;
```

when I run the above code, I get an error message

> Undefined function or method 'integral' for input arguments of type
>   'function_handle'.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

My Matlab is R2010 MATLAB

Comment: http://www.edaboard.com/thread137788.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>> fun = @(x) exp(-x.^2).*log(x).^2; 
>> q = integral(fun,2,4); 
>> q

q =

    0.0026
```

it works,what is problem?

maybe in 2010  there is function int,
http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html

please check it

Comment: also it http://autarkaw.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/how-do-i-integrate-a-continuous-function-in-matlab/

Comment: I did mistake. I just use MATLAB again

Answer (score 1):

This is not a math question, but a programming question.

Replace `integral` with `rbdthbtbtn` or something and you will get the analogous error message, which means there is no function `integral`, which in turn probably means that you do not have the toolbox you expected to have.